# Sp to return string of sequence numbers based on query against table column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence

I am working on a procedure that takes in two inputs (ID (for eg. `12345`), number of batch numbers to output (for eg.`5`))

And outputs the values from a sequence (??) or just some other way to return (for eg. '01', '02', '03', '04', '05').

That output is based on a lookup against a new batch_id column in a table that defaults the initial value to '1' (and is the same table that has already has a column for the ID) after the alter. As the client app keeps calling the SP, this column gets incremented to the max of the last output ('05') per the id ('12345'). I have the following code to get the next batch numbers using a sequence as such:

```
select btchnum_seq.nextval seq_num
from dual 
connect by level <= in_total_batches;
```

where in_total_batches is the second in param mentioned above.

1. How do i co-relate this against the column in the table that is actually holding the max value after the last run?
2. And how would i output these 5 values? As a string? If the above select was in a cursor, how would i display the records?
3. How would i take the max value of the output and update the table column to be that value at the end?

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you working with integers or strings? if you want highlight use `\`` side quote instead of `'`single quote right now looks like you are talking about strings

Comment: well the batch_num field in the table is numbers, and im guessing output the list of seqnums as integers separated by commas would be the best way??

Comment: You'd have to tell us what approach you want.  It's possible to return a comma-separated string of values.  It's possible to return a cursor from which the caller can fetch multiple row.  It's possible to write a pipelined table function that returns a virtual table.  It's possible to return a collection of numbers.  Which of these you want is something you'd need to tell us.

Comment: i think a comma separated string of values as the output parameter works fine.

Comment: OK.  What version of Oracle are you using?  Is this something that you are going to be calling in a multi-user environment where you want to avoid giving two callers the same value?  If it is, you understand that we'll have to introduce a serialization mechanism that may (substantially) decrease the scalability of your application, right?

Comment: not a multi user environment. oracle 11.2.0.

Comment: OK.  So there is only one human that will ever be using your application (at least at a time)?  That implies this is probably a homework assignment not a real project, right?

Comment: no it is a real project, but as you mentioned only one human will be accessing it at a point in time. :) it will be part of a business process run in ibm sterling for a nacha map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this (untested).  If you ever use this in a multi-user environment, be aware that you'd potentially get the same values returned in different sessions and you might get the same value returned multiple times across calls.

```
create table batch (
  batch_id integer primary key,
  last_val integer not null
);

insert into batch( batch_id, last_val )
  values( 12345, 0 );

create procedure get_next_values( p_batch_id IN batch.batch_id%type,
                                  p_num_vals IN integer,
                                  p_values  OUT varchar2 )
as
  l_start_val integer;
begin
  select last_val
    into l_start_val
    from batch
   where batch_id = p_batch_id;

  update batch
     set last_val = last_val + p_num_vals
   where batch_id = p_batch_id;

  select listagg( last_val + level, ',' )
           within group( order by level )
    into p_values
    from dual
 connect by level <= p_num_vals;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Cave. For the output itself, I need to left pad numbers into the string values. Can i use LPAD with LISTAGG? It is only needed for the output and not the update. Just out of curiosity, since you are doing the update first, should'nt the last select be select listagg(l_start_val + level ...)?

Comment: @QuickDrawMcgraw - Sure.  You can do whatever you want to the `last_val + level` expression if you want to change the format of the numbers that are part of the comma-separated string.